How can I mass activate inactive picklist values?
How can I mass activate inactive picklist values?
I have over 30 inactive picklist values which I would like to activate.
Currently I can't retrieve them using Metadata API or other means.
I tried to run the script on the page /_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Family&type=Product2
for (a of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.actionLink[Title~="Activate"]'))) {
    window.open(a.href);
}

but this doesn't work in Lightning Experience.

We need to go to Classic, allow popup on the page
_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Family&type=Product2
and execute script in Javascript console
for (a of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.actionLink[Title~="Activate"]'))) {
    window.open(a.href);
}

